# How do I get all my 'content' from the Request Body in a POST request?

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, httprequest

Well title says all I guess.

I've tried to `print_r($_SERVER)` but my 'post-request' I made with fiddler doesn't show up.

I'm really out of my mind after trying about 1 hour now :S

What I actually want is to send a POST request with JSON in the request-body. Then I want to `json_decode(request-body);` This way I can use the variables to reply. So I don't need to put my variables in the URL

Edit:

This is my POST

```
$url = 'http.........jsonAPI/jsonTestAPI.php';
$post = array("token" => "923874657382934857y32893475y43829ufhgjdkfn");
$jsonpost = json_encode($post);

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonpost);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: show us what you have for code...

Comment: first port of call should always be phpinfo(); in your PHP script to see what is available ... you'll see $_REQUEST or $_POST if they are valid & set...

Comment: What I need to establish, is the communication between a mobile app and the service. A JSON API Service. I need to receive an array with some feedkeys who can be returned. But you can't just put an array in the URL so I thought about a JSON POST Request.

Comment: could you pls mention here the code block by which you sending the POST request? I think you have missed the name of the filed in which you are submitting the data in json format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `file_get_contents('php://input');` or PHP global `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.

Comment: no idea why this was downvoted as it does exactly the right thing.

Comment: Thanks :) file_get_contents('php://input'); is just what I need.

Comment: This also works with any other HTTP methods carrying a content body, such as PUT. It is also advisable to set a maximum size for the allowed content body with the `maxlen` parameter, e.g. `file_get_contents('php://input', null, null, 0, 0x1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to get that done would be to put your json into a hidden input-field and then have the containing form being submitted using POST.